# How can I improve performance on my REST API?

Tags: python, django, rest, server, django-rest-framework

So I decided to benchmark my REST API today that I developed using Django REST Framework. The request I send is a GET request that basically retrieves the latest 50 posts from the database and returns it in JSON format.

Using Apache Benchmark, the stats were:

```
Server Software: nginx/1.4.6
Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   18.394 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Non-2xx responses:      1000
Total transferred:      5628000 bytes
HTML transferred:       5447000 bytes
Requests per second:    54.36 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       1839.442 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       18.394 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          298.79 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:       17 1137 1899.3     31   12366
Processing:    25  189 314.2     31    1418
Waiting:       24  184 309.4     29    1415
Total:         44 1326 1846.3    888   12407

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%    888
  66%   1178
  75%   1775
  80%   2286
  90%   3434
  95%   4576
  98%   7859
  99%   7922
  100%  12407 (longest request)
```

This is obviously, incredibly slow...but I'm not sure how I can improve this.

PS: I am very new to developing a server, and want to learn from this. In the above GET request, I am not doing any sort of threading whatsoever on the server side. All it simply is doing is:

```
    user_id = str(request.QUERY_PARAMS.get("user_id", None))

    cur = connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM get_posts(%s)", [user_id]) # This is a Function in the SQL database

    return Response(convertToDict(cursor))
```

I want to improve the speed of that GET request, so what can I possibly do to make it faster?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using `get_posts` in lieu of the Django ORM? This is not to say the ORM will improve performance, but using it will give you more details using e.g. [django debug toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar).

Answer (score 2):

Well, I am a little surprised to see a raw SQL query (that's another show) but you can do all sorts of things.

**TL;DR**

### Upfront

Doing performance testing is great, regularly benchmarking and recording those outcomes over time is a good practice but benchmarking can be tricky to do properly: you have to take software and hardware into account - the outcomes of your tests will heavily depend on the interactions of those two things. Do your best to replicate your production environment for these things and try out different configurations (you are [12factor](http://12factor.net), right?) to determine a good fit.

Side note: I'm not horribly familiar with AB but looks like you are also returning HTML according to the output that doesn't seem to be intended behavior.

### Fixing the problem

The first thing to do is evaluate what you have done in a thoughtful way.

1. Inspect the queries

Use things like `django-debug-toolbar` to see if you have some query bottlenecks - many queries that are chained together, long running queries, etc. If you need to get more granular, your database probably has logging facilities to record the long queries.

Assuming your data is pretty normalized (in the sense of normal forms), this may be a place to introduce denormalization so you don't have to traverse as many relationships.

You could also introduce raw SQL (but you seem to already be doing that).

2. Inspect your business logic

You should be diligent in making sure your business logic is being placed in the correct parts of the request, response cycle. Many times you put things in places just to get it working, maybe your initial decision is finding it's limits.

It seems like you are doing something very simple: get the last 50 entries in a table. If you are computing whether or not a post is included, you should probably leave that to the database - it should be handling all of the logic when it comes to what data to retrieve.

3. Inspect supporting code

While you're at it, try doing some more performance testing and see what areas of your code are lagging behind. Maybe there are things you can do that will improve your code (while being readable and understandable by others) and give you a performance bump. List comprehensions, generators, taking advantage of prefetch_ and select_related, taking care to lazily evaluate queries - all of these things are worth implementing because their functionality is well documented and understood. That said, be sure to document these decisions carefully for your future self and possibly others.

I'm not really familiar with your implementation of the view code as it relates to the Django REST framework, I would probably stick to the JSON serializers that come with it.

4. Work arounds

Another useful trick is to do things like implement a [pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/) strategy (but with the [REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/) most likely) so the data only get transferred in small pieces to the client. This will be heavily dependent on the use case.

This serves as a nice introduction to:

### Throwing Software at the Problem

You can use a [cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/) to save data in the RAM of your server so it is quickly accessed by Django.

Generally, what cache will work best will depend on the data itself. It may be the case that using a search engine to store documents that you query frequently will be most useful. But, a good start is [Redis](http://redis.io). You can read all about implementing the cache from a variety of sources but a good place to search around with Django is on [Django Packages](http://djangopackages.com).

### Throwing Hardware at the Problem

Speed can also be about hardware. You should think about the requirements of your software and it's dependencies. Do some testing, search around and experiment with what's right for you. Throwing more hardware at a problem has severe diminishing marginal returns.

Answer (score 1):

can you post your get_posts(user_id) method??.

Steps to improve your performance

1. Make improvements on get_posts() method. You need to make sure that there are minimum number of queries to the database. Try to get the results by using one .filter and make use of select_related, prefetch related to reduce the database calls. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related
2. Use .extra to the .filter if required, Through which you can add additional attribute to the model instance which cannot be done through a single query https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#extra
3. Make these changes to the get_posts() and see how your GET request responds. If it still lags you can opt for caching.

Most of the consumption of time will be for the database calls. If you optimize the get_posts() you might get satisfied with the performance

Comment: May I suggest to add step _0. measure performance of all components involved_. you are making an educated guess which is probably right, yet the first rule in improving performance is to understand where time is spent...